# Angular 9 submit form from child component

Tags: angular, parent-child, angular-reactive-forms

I'm stucked in a problem that I don't even know if is possible to solve.
My requirement is that I have a form that can have many customizations, but the submit is the same for each customization
To avoid duplication of code I was thinking to create a child component where I inject the html elements.
I created a stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wah7x4

My problem is that im not able to submit the form in the child component.
So, is this possible to pass a form to a child component and then submit the form inside the child component?

Comment: what is not working properly, can you explain more here?

Comment: I will try... I have many parent with forms but only one logic for submit. I want to pass html elements to the child with templateOutlet and execute the logic of the submit inside child element in order to have only one point in the code where I perform submit operations

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-betfsb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.html Does this solve your problem

Comment: you could put your submit logic in a service, and provide that service in each of your parent components. so code is still in one place and can be easily reused

Comment: Yes, this is a possibility. But if I put the logic on a service, templating of the form is useless 

Comment: @GaurangDhorda probably you solve my issue... How can I mark it as response?

Comment: @Davide.77 I have answer the same, you can check out answer too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Working demo**, In this [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-betfsb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

First, as you already passes `parentForm` to `child-component`, then you only need to have to put `Submit` logic inside child-component like below..

```
<form [formGroup]="parentForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
    {{parentForm.value | json}}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>
```

And in child-component.ts file you need submit() function.

```
submit(){
   console.log('submit')
}
```

This way you can solve your submit logic implementation inside child-component.

Answer (score 0):

So, if you want to submit form, from child component, you must have some property in child with @output decorator to emit some event that take parent form knows , that that's need to submit.[@output decorator description](https://angular.io/api/core/Output)

Comment: The problem is that i dont know how to trigger the submit event. The (ngsubmit) method is on parent and the target is to execute submit on the child. In this way i will have the submit code on the child. If I emit the event, I will have the logic on parent for each customization.